# randomly split dataframe into groups with even distribution of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe of two groups (`A` and `B`) and within those groups, 6 subgroups (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`). Example data below:

```
index   group    subgroup    value
0       A        a           1
1       A        b           1
2       A        c           1
3       A        d           1
4       A        e           1
5       A        f           1
6       B        a           1
7       B        b           1
8       B        c           1
9       B        d           1
10      B        e           1
11      B        f           1
...     ...      ...         ...
```

While I've only listed 12 rows here of values that equal 1, there are in fact 300 rows in the real dataset (values equal 2, 3, etc). I'm trying to randomly split the dataframe into 6 batches of 50 values. However, I'd like each batch to contain an even distribution of `group` values (so 25 A's and 25 B's) and approximately even distribution of `subgroup` values.

For example, batch_1 might contain:

25 `A`'s which contain 4 `a`'s, 5 `b`'s, 4 `c`'s, 4 `d`'s, 5 `e`'s and 3 `f`'s. And 25 `B`'s which contain 5 `a`'s, 4 `b`'s, 3 `c`'s, 5 `d`'s, 4 `e`'s and 4 `f`'s.

These 6 batches will be given to 1 user. (So I actually need to randomly split the dataframe into multiple *different* 6 batches for more users.) But I can't tell whether this is a problem in which the dataframe should be randomly split or sampled from. Does anyone have advice on how to achieve this?

This may be helpful but doesn't ensure an even distribution of values: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/break-list-chunks-size-n-python/

Comment: could try to groupby the group column and then use sample to get a random sample, repeat the same for the subgroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a few techniques

1. use `pd.factorize()` to turn categorical data into values for each category
2. calculate a value/factor *f* that represents a pairing of *group / subgroup*
3. randomise this a bit `np.random.uniform()` with min & max close to 1
4. once have a value that represents grouping, can `sort_values()` and `reset_index()` to have a clean ordered index
5. finally working out grouping by integer remainder

```
group = list("ABCD")
subgroup = list("abcdef")
df = pd.DataFrame([{"group":group[random.randint(0,len(group)-1)], 
 "subgroup":subgroup[random.randint(0,len(subgroup)-1)],
 "value":random.randint(1,3)} for i in range(300)])

bins=6
dfc = df.assign(
    # take into account concentration of group and subgroup
    # randomise a bit....
    f = ((pd.factorize(df["group"])[0] +1)*10 + 
            (pd.factorize(df["subgroup"])[0] +1) 
            *np.random.uniform(0.99,1.01,len(df))
        ),
).sort_values("f").reset_index(drop=True).assign(
    gc=lambda dfa: dfa.index%(bins)
).drop(columns="f")

# check distribution ... used plot for SO
dfc.groupby(["gc","group","subgroup"]).count().unstack(0).plot(kind="barh")
# every group same size...
# dfc.groupby("gc").count()

# now it's easy to get each of the cuts.... 0 through 5
# dfcut0 = dfc.query("gc==0").drop(columns="gc").copy().reset_index(drop=True)
# dfcut0
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: thank you so much! The level of detail in your step-by-step instructions is extremely helpful. Can you please explain why you used integer remainder in `gc=lambda dfa: dfa.index%(bins)`?

Comment: it's a simple case of that's what put's it into one of 6 bins.  so has to an integer and a remainder.  i.e. allocated row by row to one of the bins,  not near the bin but the bin

Comment: Could I ask for your advice again on your post? I'm now trying to do the exact opposite task, i.e., split my dataframe into bins of 50 so that each bin contains 6 unique values. Each batch should contain an even distribution of subgroup values and approximately even distribution of group values. However, switching `group` and `subgroup` in your code does not randomly split the group values into equal amounts. Do you have advice? (Also please let me know if I should open a new question! I'd be happy to do so, but the question seems repetitive to this original post.)

Comment: @psychcoder note calculation of `f` is biased to group over subgroup (multiplies by 10).  Adjusting calc of `f` should achieve what you want (subgroup as driver)